# I have branched off a branch and want to push my changes. Do I push changes to the original branch or merge the two branches?

Tags: git

I have branch ticket-123/fancy_feature, and I branch off of that to work on some styling on branch ticket-123/fancy_feature_styles.

After I make my changes on branch ticket-123/fancy_feature_styles do I push to branch ticket-123/fancy_feature or merge with it?

New to anything but intro git, and want to learn the best practices, any feedback or thoughts would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, a merge is all that is needed.

After finalizing your commits on `ticket-123/fancy_feature_styles`:

```
git checkout ticket-123/fancy_feature
git merge ticket-123/fancy_feature_styles
```

If you were contributing to a larger project with several developers working on the same code, you would probably push `ticket-123/fancy_feature_styles` to a remote branch, then open a pull request to have it merged into `ticket-123/fancy_feature`.